# Can you use jquery data while selecting using the class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

i.e. `$(".class")[0].data().num;`

I ask because a console.log says data() is an undefined function.

```
<div class="class" data-num="1"></div>
<div class="class" data-num="2"></div>
<div class="class" data-num="3"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML and what are you trying to get

Comment: It may be returning undefined because your `div` doesn't have any `data` attribute

Comment: It does in the html I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the following markup:

```
<html> 
 <body> 
  <div class="class" data-test="1"></div>
  <div class="class" data-test="2"></div>
  <div class="class" data-test="3"></div>
 </body> 
</html>
```

If you are trying to get the data attribute of the first `.class` element:

```
$('.class').eq(0).attr('data-test'); // returns 1
```

If you have assinged some data:

```
$('.class').eq(0).data();
```

Answer (score 1):

try removing the [0] or use it like `$($(".class")[0])` because [0] is giving you the HTML - DOM-Element of the firtst entry

Comment: TBH, `$($(".class")[0])` hurt my eyes. You should use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: I'm trying to get one element specific class' data while looping through them